# Tried switching between python verions. Ended up messing the whole thing. How to fix it?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, xubuntu, python, update-alternatives

I actually have three questions:

1. So I was trying to switch between **python2.7** and **python3.4**. I
   added both the alternatives using `update-alternatives`, giving
   priorities 1 and 2, respectively. It was set to manual mode so I
   configured it and tried running `python`. I don't know what happened
   here but it didn't work. It was working fine before setting the
   alternatives. *But*, instead, when I entered `python2` it worked
   just fine and launched **python2.7**. Similarly, entering `python3`
   launched **python3.4**. And this got me confused a bit.

   Isn't `python` supposed to be a generic command to run either v2.7
   or v.3.4 based on the configuration?
2. Now, *very gallantly*, I tried fixing this on my own, without
   feeling the need to look up what the problem was (naive, I know). I
   played around with it a bit. Removed the alternatives one-by-one
   using `remove` ( should've used `remove-all` *sighs* ) but,
   suspiciously enough, when I ran `update-alternatives --list python`,
   it still was showing the alternatives. *Confusion++*.

   What's the reason behind this? Why were those still being shown?
3. Anyway, assuming they were removed, I added the alternatives again
   and, in the hope of having fixed the problem, tried running
   `python`. Alas, it didn't work... displaying the following line:

   `bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad
   interpreter: No such file or directory`

   Next, tried running `python2`. Bam! This time, this one didn't work
   either! Producing a similar output:

   `bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad
   interpreter: No such file or directory`

   Same for `python3`. Output:

   `bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad
   interpreter: No such file or directory`

   So, what am I missing here and where lies the problem? Please
   elaborate.

PS : 
Pardon my ignorance. The questions might be silly but It's only recently that I started learning all this. I am pretty much a noob.

PPS :
I am running Xubuntu 15.04.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- py2 and py3 are usually found side by side and like I discovered better left for the system to pick which version it needs. If you want to use any version then you have to point whatever app you are using to the version you want.
- Running "python" will always run the 2.X version, but running "python3" or "python2" will give you the respective versions.
- Run **following commands** in terminal:

  `sudo apt-get update`

  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python`
- **Another solution** will be to use the dpkg since this doesn't depend on
  python, but requires more effort go [**here**](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dpkg.html) for this option. This will mean you will download all required packages. Hope it Helps.

Comment: Can you revisit your layout George... that's the only thing keeping me from upvoting